# Cannot install cffi-1.15.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64 wheel on Python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6, python-cffi

I am attempting to package a custom built Python wheel package for offline installation, which indirectly depends on `cffi`. To do so, I call `python3 -m pip download my-custom-package -d package-content`. I then create a 7zip self extracting installer that uses a Windows batch script to handle the installtion by using the `--find-links` functionality of `pip`.

I constrain my package's `setup.py` to Python 3.6, and use the Python 3.6 interpreter to run the `pip download` command. I was under the impression that this would retrieve wheel packages capable of being installed on any version of Python 3.x newer than 3.6 (in most cases).

`cffi-1.15.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64` is fetched when packaging the offline installer for Windows x86_64, and is able to be installed on Python 3.6 through 3.9. However, when I attempt to install it on Python 3.10, I get the following output:
`ERROR: cffi-1.15.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

If I change the name of the file to `cffi-1.15.1-`**cp310**`-`**cp310m**`-win_amd64.whl`, then it suddenly installs correctly (and is useable). This leads me to believe that there is nothing internal to the file indicating that it is not compatible with Python 3.10, but rather `pip` is parsing the `ABI` from the filename, and barfing on it.

Is this a known bug with `pip`? My `pip` version on the packaging side is `21.3.1`, and on the installation side is `23.0.1`. My current plan is to run the `pip` download command multiple times, specifying each Python minor version between 3.6 and 3.10. This is cumbersome however, and if there is a documented bug explaing this as isolated specifically to `cffi-1.15.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64`, then I could possible look into alternate, more elegant, solutions. Is it perhaps a limitation of the `cp3x` `ABI`?

Comment: No, it's not a bug, but if you rename a wheel's tags to something else, you're playing with fire and haven taken all of the safeties off.

Comment: I wasn't saying that renaming the wheel was a viable solution to my problem. Rather, that piece of information shows that there is not some version range internal to the wheel file which indicates it is incompatible with Python 3.10. If `pip` was determining compatibility from a source in addition to the filename, I would expect the wheel file to *remain* incompatible for installation even *after* renaming it.

Comment: "*This leads me to believe that there is nothing internal to the file indicating that it is not compatible with Python 3.10, but rather pip is parsing the ABI from the filename, and barfing on it.*" Yes, exactly.

"*Is this a known bug with pip?*" Not a bug at all. If you can rename the file what could prevent you to edit the content of the wheel (it's just a zip archive, so you can unzip it, edit and re-pack back)? It's like editing an executable file with a hex editor — you can do it but all segfaults after that is your punishment. The bottom line is — **don't do it !!!***

Comment: Well, you're correct in that `pip` doesn't determine it further from the contents of the `.whl`, it just unzips it where it belongs. (Well, it might look at the `Requires-Python` metadata within, too, but AFAIK there's no binary compatibility metadata within the wheel).

Comment: The CFFI source code contains conditional compilation directives depending on the CPython version, which means that it may possibly work in simple cases but it *will* break in others.